# How to get selected row id using button and send a SQL Query to update database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have code that displays a table from SQL Server with `WorkSchedule` the `User` wants to pick, however I need to button to update the attribute in my table which is `WorkScheduleStatus` to `Pending` after the User has selected which `WorkSchedule` they want using a button.

However now I am having problems updating only the selected row because all the buttons update all the `WorkScheduleStatus` in my SQL Server table.

I need help in getting row id so I can update the database through which row I have selected using the button but my code ends up updating all the `WorkScheduleStatus` to `Test`.

I want to get the selected row and then update it according to the one I selected and then update it without it disturbing the other `WorkScheduleStatus`. Is there anyone able to help me? Thanks in advance, because I really need it.

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult DisplaySchedule(WorkScheduleModel workScheduleModel)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();

    SqlDataReader dr;

    connectionString();
    con.Open();

    com.Connection = con;
    com.CommandText = "update WorkSchedule set WorkScheduleStatus ='test' ";

    dr = com.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        con.Close();
        return View("DisplaySchedule");
    }
    else
    {
        con.Close();
        return View("DisplaySchedule");
    }

    void connectionString()
    {
        con.ConnectionString = "";
    }
}
```

View markup:

```
@model IEnumerable<Starbucks.Models.WorkScheduleModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/PartTimerLayout.cshtml";
}

<h1 class="text-center"> Apply Workshifts</h1>
<hr />

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                From (DateTime)
            </th>
            <th>
                To (DateTime)
            </th>
            <th>
                Day
            </th>
            <th>
                Status
            </th>
            <th>
                Work Descriptions
            </th>
            <th>
                Branch
            </th>
            <th>
                Manager
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkScheduleFromDateTime)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkScheduleToDateTime)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkScheduleFromDateTime.DayOfWeek)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkScheduleStatus)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkDescriptions.WorkDescriptionName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Branches.BranchName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Staff.StaffName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <form method="post">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn-success" value="Select" asp-route-id="@item.WorkScheduleID" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DisplaySchedule", "PartTimeController")'" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Due to you have `asp-route-id` in the razor view,so you could receive the route data with name `id` like below:

   ```
   public ActionResult DisplaySchedule(Guid? id)
   ```
2. You use `onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DisplaySchedule", "PartTimeController")'"`,please be sure that the second parameter of `Url.Action` should be `PartTime` which is your controller name(i.e. you have a `PartTimeController`,the controller name is `PartTime` instead of `PartTimeController`).
3. No need to use onclick event.Because you have used the tag helper `asp-route-id`,it could generate the `formaction` url and the form submit depends on the `formaction` url.
   [image]

   If your Razor View named `DisplaySchedule.cshtml` and it is in the `PartTime` folder.Just using single `asp-route-id` would generate the correct url like:`PartTime/DisplaySchedule/1`.You could also specify the action and controller entirely:

   ```
   <button type="submit" class="btn-success" value="Select" asp-route-id="@item.WorkScheduleID"asp-action="DisplaySchedule" asp-controller="PartTime"/>
   ```
4. Update the raw with selected row id:

   ```
   public ActionResult DisplaySchedule(Guid? id)
   {
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
       SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();

       SqlDataReader dr;

       connectionString();
       con.Open();

       com.Connection = con;
       com.CommandText = "update WorkSchedule set WorkScheduleStatus ='test' where WorkScheduleID = @WorkScheduleID";
       com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkScheduleID", id);

       dr = com.ExecuteReader();

       if (dr.Read())
       {
           con.Close();
           var model = db.WorkScheduleModel.ToList();//select all the data in your database
           return View("DisplaySchedule",model);
           return View("DisplaySchedule");
       }
       else
       {
           con.Close();
           var model = db.WorkScheduleModel.ToList();//select all the data in your database
           return View("DisplaySchedule",model);
       }

       void connectionString()
       {
           con.ConnectionString = "xxxxx";
       }
   }
   ```

**Update:**

For how to return model,refer to:

```
var model = db.WorkScheduleModel.ToList();//select all the data in your database
return View("DisplaySchedule",model);
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth guide, I really needed this and It really helped me a lot, instead of using "public ActionResult DisplaySchedule(int id)" I had to change it a bit to "public ActionResult DisplaySchedule(Guid? id)" . Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: How do I fix this error :                                                    
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null.                          How do I pass a new model in my controller when it is ActionResult ?

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using a data layer, and have some using statements in there so your connections are properly used and pooled. But that's beyond the scope of your question. You need to [add a parameter to your query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) like so, but use whatever your column name is, and your property for the id is.

```
com.CommandText = "update WorkSchedule set WorkScheduleStatus ='test' where [yourColumnName] = @id ";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", workScheduleModel.yourIdProperty);
```

Also be sure you look at that link I have there; you don't need an entire data reader. Just executeNonQuery.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was what I was missing!